# How do memory management properties affect cells of an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

In my iPhone development book, I'm seeing some strange coding examples in regard to what an array does when objects are added to the array and when the whole array is released. One code example has the following properties on an instance array:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

The author adds an object to the array and, immediately after, releases his pointer to the object. Won't the array cell now point to garbage data? Unless, behind the scenes, the array cell retains the object when added.

```
SomeObject* someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
[self.myArray addObject:someObject];
[someObject release];
```

The author also releases the the pointer to the array without first going through each array cell and releasing the individual objects. This is a memory leak unless, behind the scenes, each cell is sent a *release* message;.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.myArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: Both your 'unless' are actually how they work. NSMutableArray's addObject retains the object and all the retained objects are released when the array is dealloced.

Comment: Is this because the array has the `retain` property or do all NSMutableArray's exhibit this behavior? Where is the documentation on this?

Comment: Please see my answer on the concept of "you need to retain what you want to use latter" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless, behind the scenes, the array cell retains the object when added.

Yes, this happens.

> ... unless, behind the scenes, each cell is sent a release message.

This also happens.

You have answered your own question.

Here is a quote from [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF):

> And when you add an object to an
>   NSMutableArray object, the object
>   isn’t copied, (unless you pass YES as
>   the argument to
>   initWithArray:copyItems:). Rather, an
>   object is added directly to an array.
>   In a managed memory environment, an
>   object receives a retain message when
>   it’s added; in a garbage collected
>   environment, it is strongly
>   referenced. When an array is
>   deallocated in a managed memory
>   environment, each element is sent a
>   release message.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in C or C++ where you constantly worry about whether to delete an object or not for the fear of it is still being used somewhere else, Objective-C (or rather it's actually Cocoa SDK) uses the mechanism of reference counting or ownership.

You might already know how it works but you need to also know that in Cocoa, if an object A needs to use another object B it should own (i.e. retain) it. That object A should not rely on some other object C already retained B, because it cannot know when C releases it. So in your case, since NSArray needs to use all objects added to it latter during its lifetime, it needs to retain all the objects. And because of that, when the array is de-alloc-ed, it needs to release them.

This concept of "you need to retain what you want to use latter" is very important when you are dealing of lots of objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are several places in apple development guides that explain that is a good practice to take the ownership of an object (send a retain message) if you plan to use it later. You should do it so that the object is not destroyed while you still might need to access it.

Considering that, you were right assuming that the NSArray retains the object when it is added to the collection, as it still might try to access it afterwards.

You can check the Memory Management Programming Guide

> When you add an object to a collection such as an array, dictionary, or set, the collection takes ownership of it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW3

or the Collections Programming Topics for more details

> ...  In a managed memory environment, an object receives a retain message when it’s added.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW1

Answer (score 1):

- You're right on the first point.  When an object is added to an array, the array retains the object.  Thus, for an object that has been previously retained, it is necessary to release it after adding it to the array or you can end up with a memory leak.
- Likewise, when an object is removed
  from an array, the array releases the
  object.  So, if you want to keep it,
  you'll need to retain it.
- When an array is released, as you
  surmised, the array will release all
  the objects it contains.  Thus,
  releasing each object individually is
  not necessary and, in fact, would
  raise an exception.
- Finally, regarding the line of code
  in -viewDidUnload that you quoted:

  ```
  self.myArray = nil;
  ```

This works properly with regard to memory management as long as the myArray property was synthesized as follows:

```
@synthesize myArray;
```

Synthesizing creates a setter that effectively does the following:

```
- (void)setMyArray(NSMutableArray *)anArray
{
    if (![myArray isEqual:anArray]) {
        [myArray release];
        myArray = anArray;
        [myArray retain];
    }
}
```

So, when called, the above setter will first release the old array (as long as it's not the same object as the new array.)  Then, it will retain the new array, which in this case is nil.  Note that retaining nil will just do nothing, and won't trigger an error.

Of course, if you don't synthesize the myArray property, or if you override the setter, you will have memory problems unless you also release the old value & retain the new in your setter.